# Accessing NODE_ENV environment variable in React on Rails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-on-rails

I've got a [React on Rails](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLiZbcv5HTAhWCrlQKHUfPBV4QFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fshakacode%2Freact_on_rails&usg=AFQjCNFDDiPMwhIXuYb_KK7C6fd8rxA16w&sig2=BGDX_OnFSzmUbmzJG3z-eA&bvm=bv.152174688,d.cGw) application that hits an API. I want to configure the API endpoint to `localhost` for development and to my deployed app's URL for production.

**client/package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "build:production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
 },
```

**client/webpack.config.js**

```
const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/Main/startup/registration',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/../app/assets/webpack',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
  ]
}
```

I see that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is available in config/webpack.config.js (used here to add source map devtools to the module exports), but I'd like a way to see what the environment is in my React code somewhere in `client/`. What are my options if any?

Comment: I'm not sure about React on Rails, but in my React environment I can access the same variable - process.env.NODE_ENV. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, `process` isn't defined in `/client` unfortunately. It is in *webpack.config* but some way to access it or pass it to the client directory would be ideal

Answer (score 3):

I just used `process.env.NODE_ENV` in a Redux action file successfully. I'm exporting NODE_ENV in webpack with plugin definition shown below in `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('ENV_VALUE')
        }
    })
]
```